# Unable to locate package - cannot download any apts

Tags: apt, package-management

I cannot get packages using, for example:

```
sudo apt install ls
```

The results I get are:

```
$ sudo apt install ls
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ls
```

I am using Ubuntu Server 17 and I can ping outside to the rest of the world but cannot download apts.

As best as I can tell, the `sources.list` is okay.  It has not been edited since I did a clean install a few days ago.

Comment: `ls` isn't a package - it's a program provided by the `coreutils` package

Answer (score 1):

ls is a command, which is already included in your standard release.

The command returns a

```
Unable to locate package ls
```

Because it is not a package.